# SharePoint 2010 sandboxed deployment error - partial trust app domain

Tags: .net, sharepoint

When I attempt to deploy a sandboxed SP 2010 project, I receive the following error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.

Any ideas about what is causing this, or how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all your code is authorized to run in a sandbox. It is hard to tell more without seeing the source code.

Comment: I've tried deploying with an empty class, but get the same error.